# swipe to check/uncheck in QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, swipe, qlistwidget

I would like to set a QListWidget in PyQt5 to check or uncheck the check boxes when I swipe.

Here is my interface:

[image]

And my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class VerifyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VerifyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.listWidget = QListWidget()

        for i in range(100):
            item = QListWidgetItem("Item %i" % i)
            # could be Qt.Unchecked; setting it makes the check appear
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

        runButton = QPushButton("Run")
        runButton.clicked.connect(self.exec)

        cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

        horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 1)

        buttonsLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        buttonsLayout.addStretch(1)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(runButton)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(cancelButton)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(horizontalLayout)
        mainLayout.addSpacing(12)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Config Dialog")
        self.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = VerifyDialog()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to click on Item 4 and have it uncheck (it's easier than clicking the box), and then I want to drag down and have lots of other items uncheck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `itemEntered` signal that sends you the object under the mouse.

```
self.listWidget.itemEntered.connect(lambda item: item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked if item.checkState()==Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked))
```

**Complete code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class VerifyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VerifyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.listWidget = QListWidget()

        self.listWidget.itemEntered.connect(lambda item: item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked if item.checkState()==Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked))


        for i in range(100):
            item = QListWidgetItem("Item %i" % i)
            # could be Qt.Unchecked; setting it makes the check appear
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

        runButton = QPushButton("Run")
        runButton.clicked.connect(self.exec)

        cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

        horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 1)

        buttonsLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        buttonsLayout.addStretch(1)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(runButton)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(cancelButton)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(horizontalLayout)
        mainLayout.addSpacing(12)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Config Dialog")
        self.show()


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = VerifyDialog()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yep, I was just checking it out. It needs some improvements, but it's mostly there.

Comment: Okay, I made the improvements. Now it remembers the state change of the first item clicked on and then propagates that when you drag to other items.

Comment: @vy32 Use the lambda function so you do not have to create a new function. You have tried my answer.

Comment: @vy32 If you want to make a change you would have done editing your question. Surely the change will be eliminated.

Comment: Why do you think that code should not be edited? I see code edited all the time on SO; please provide a reference for it not being edited.